# Does the QuorumChain model reward nodes for determining the next block?

Tags: blockchain, quorum

I know Proof Of Work models such as `Bitcoin` has mining which rewards the miner for finding the next block. However, do such rewards exist in the `QuorumChain` model, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Quorum is built on ethereum (EVM) and uses a different type of consensus algorithm, which doesn't need any incentive model to create blocks. Also gas price is zero in quorum blockchain, which means even you require certain number of gas to execute tasks on blockchain you don't need to pay in ether, which works fine without creating any new ether in the ecosystem.